# Calling an Enum value from an SQL database inside java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I am making a login frame/class with Java that I will need to get enum values A,B or C from my SQL database when someone puts in their username and password.

I tried to make a new class to call the database but I didn't make it work. I also tried to make the call in this class but I was not able to make it work either. I have been trying to look it up for two days now but no cigar. As you can tell I am a newbie.

I know I will have to use something like else `if (rs.next() && account_permission.tolowercase().equals("b"))` in the if statements.

I do understand that this code only opens the admin frame regardless of their account_permissions/enum.

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    String sql = "select * from members where UserName = ? and Password = ?";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, txtusername.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtpassword.getText());
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password are correct");
            AdminJFrame s = new AdminJFrame();
            this.dispose();
            s.setVisible(true);
        }
        else 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password did not match");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: a. Stop embedding security relate code "select * from users..." create a proc in mySQL that takes usname and pword and ONLY returns success or failure. b. Enums are evil!  use ints, longs, anything to set their menu privileges.

Comment: Okey will do as I said I am a nubie just tought it would be nice to learn how  to use them ^^.

Comment: Enums in java are best used ONLY internally within Java.  they only really correlate well there.  Anything from the outside and you can hose yourself.  They are sort of like constants that you can pass around.  They ARE great for limiting the things you can pass to a function and things like that though.

Comment: Awesome answers! Thanks you I will read and learn more and fix my problems atm using ints instead ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your SQL. Be specific about which fields you're selecting:

```
String sql = "select Role from members where UserName = ? and Password = ?";
```

I'm assuming your field that holds the A, B or C is called `Role`.

Now modify your code to detect the correct role:

```
    if (rs.next()) {
        if ("B".equals(rs.getString("Role"))) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password are correct");
            AdminJFrame s = new AdminJFrame();
            this.dispose();
            s.setVisible(true);
        } else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You don't have the required role");
    } else 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password did not match");
```

Comment: Oh, didn't realize your "Role" field could be null. I changed the code in my answer to be null safe.

Comment: Hehe naa was not the problem works now ^^ I for got to connect to the database because I changed JFrame and for got to add one line of code and thank you your answer is perfect.